# Isn't webpack dev server generating bundle.js in memory?

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, frontend, webpack-dev-server

I have a file structure as below:

```
Project
 |
 +-- src/
 |   |
 |   +-- index.js
 |
 +-- index.html
 |
 +-- webpack.config.js
```

src/index.js:

```
document.write("Hello World.");
```

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>webpack learning</title>

    <script src="builds/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'builds'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  }
};
```

When I run webpack-dev-server in the Project directory, webpack-dev-server starts normally and prints "webpack: bundle is now VALID." However, when I launch a browser and go to localhost:8080, the console complains that bundle.js is not found. Indeed, there is no such folder named "build" with bundle.js in it. But, isn't webpack-dev-server generating bundle.js in memory? Any configuration problems involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to see the command you are running, however if I had to take a guess at this one I would say you may not be setting `--content-base` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase

Comment: And it would also be useful to explicitly declare [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath).

Comment: When I add output.publicPath and set it to "builds", everything works just fine. It seems that when webpack-dev-server is generating bundle.js in memory, it puts that file in the directory specified by output.publicPath and ignores what directory the "output.path" is set to. Because whatever output.path is set to, as long as output.publicPath remains "builds", no error appears in the console and the browser renders "Hello World."